# File created by a dependency is deleted when main target is completed

Tags: gnu-make

I have a question regarding the behaviour of gnu make. Specifically, if a dependency target produces a file that did not already exist, it is deleted when the "master" target is complete.

I am sure there are very good reasons to why this happens, but how can I work around it?

I have elaborated on the situation below and added an example Makefile showing the concept of what I am trying to do.

*Thank you for your input.*

**Situation:**

The purpose of the example file below (working "dummy example" of the actual Makefile) is to produce "html" AND "pdf" from a Markdown file.

The default target is `pdf`, which will recursively call the target `%.pdf`, who in turns has `%.html`, and consequently `%.md`, as dependencies. So far so good, if the directory contains a markdown file only I will produce the "html" file before the "pdf" is produced.

If you run the example you will notice that the "html" file is deleted after the `%.pdf` target is complete. The output in the terminal will be:

```
usr@cmptr $ make
Generated: sof_example.md
Generated: sof_example.html
Generated: sof_example.pdf
rm sof_example.html sof_example.md
usr@cmptr $
```

However, if the file(s) exists prior to executiong `make` the output is:

```
usr@cmptr $ make clean
usr@cmptr $ touch sof_example.html sof_example.md
usr@cmptr $ make
Generated: sof_example.pdf
usr@cmptr $
```

Is there any way I can fix this elegantly, i.e. without adding more recursive calls, or specific to the example having `html` as a dependency is not desirable as `%.pdf` would be performed every time `make` is executed.

---

**Example file:**

```make
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# summary: Make file generating 'html' and 'pdf' from a markdown ('md') file
# usage:   make
# note:    Recursive
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

TARGETS := sof_example
SHELL=/bin/bash

.PHONY: all clean
all: pdf

# Dummy target, the markdown file will normally located in TARGETS
%.md:
    @touch $(@)
    @printf "Generated: %s\n" $(@) 

# HTML target: Generates HTML file from markdown
%.html: %.md
    @touch $(@)
    @printf "Generated: %s\n" $(@) 

# PDF target: Generates pdf version of the HTML, e.g. using `wkhtmltopdf`
%.pdf: %.html
    @touch $(@)
    @printf "Generated: %s\n" $(@) 

pdf html:
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory $(addsuffix .$(@), $(TARGETS))

# Will remove ALL files with name TARGETS, regardless of suffix
clean:
    @$(RM) $(TARGETS).*

# EoF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing happens because the chaining of your implicit patterm rules:

```
%.md -> %.html -> %.pdf
```

leads `make` to deduce that the `%.md` and the `%.html` are merely intermediate
by-products of making the `%.pdf`, for any given `%`. And in that case its
default assumption is that you don't want to keep the intermediates.

If you *do* want to keep intermediates you can tell `make` so by declaring
the special target `.SECONDARY:` anywhere in the makefile.

```
.SECONDARY:
```

with no prerequisites will preserve all intermediates. With prerequisites,
e.g.

```
.SECONDARY: $(addsuffix .html,$(TARGETS))
```

only those intermediates that are prerequisites will be preserved.

See [4.9 Special Built-in Target Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html)